# Accessing file meta-data within Python/wxPython

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, icons, wxpython

I would like to write a Python/wxPython app that implements wx.FileDropTarget. This part is easy. I would also like to show the file icon as it is dragged over the app window and then display a proxy with file icon (and other meta-data, perhaps, like size) within the app window.

I would like to implement this on Windows 7. But I am interested in being able to make this work on OS X and Linux as well.

I have googled and searched through Python v2.7.1 documentation - but to no avail. I am somewhat new the ways of Windows, so if there is a way to divine a BMP or ICO file that is associated with a file - then I am okay with going that route...

Any example code is always appreciated.

Comment: You want to know what it is *while it's being dragged*? I don't believe you can do that anywhere. You can recognise that something is being dragged over and get information of its MIME type too, I believe, but I don't believe you can get the actual data (it would be a big security risk - dragging my passwords file or a string of passwords to a different folder or a browser or something and I happen to move over something else in the meantime and it steals it?

Comment: I am not looking to run this in a browser or other secure sandbox. I am pretty sure that I could write a desktop python app that would search for password files and email them or ftp them to some remote server. So, I don't see how dragging over an application window would create a greater security risk. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it's just as great a security risk. You could have slightly malicious software installed almost as easily as you could visit a slightly malicious website.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, and I've known IT specialists who felt the only safe computer was one that was disconnected from all networks and powered off. Anything else == great security risk. I see it as more of a continuum. And, fwiw, I am just throwing together a proof of principle demo - the purpose of which is, ironically, sending dropped file to another machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's not only one portable way to accomplish this ... on windows platforms, default icons for file types associations are stored on the system registry (except for executables where the icon is in the exe resources) and on linux platforms it depends on the desktop environment, each one has its own standards ... so i don't think there's an "universal" way to do that.

Comment: That's okay. I don't need a universal way, and I realize that some OSes may not even have a notion of a "file icon". So, what I am getting from your answer is that I should research how to get file icon from system registry on Windows (except for .exe and others?) - and, if I get this working, then I can turn my attention to other platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This example should get you started for finding file icons in windows:

```
from _winreg import *

extension = '.html'

reg = OpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, extension)
(value, vtype) = QueryValueEx(reg, None)
print "file type is:", value

reg = OpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, value + '\DefaultIcon')
(value, vtype) = QueryValueEx(reg, None)
print value, vtype
```

**%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,-17 2**

...at least that's what it is on my system.